# Samsung BIOS update fails from Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bios

I downloaded and ran the BIOS updater from Samsung's website. It fails with the error message:

> Loading driver failed. Restart system.

What's going on?

My laptop is a Samsung Q330.

Answer (score 2):

Download and install Easy Display Manager before running the BIOS Updater. I'm not exactly sure why, but the Easy Display Manager is a prerequisite to updating the BIOS. When it's installed, run the BIOS updater under windows 7 compatibility mode. It should automatically download and install the BIOS problem-free from here.

If something goes wrong after the new BIOS is successfully downloaded, try finding the downloaded BIOS (in the same folder as the updater. It has a name like ITEM_20130321_500_WIN_06UU.exe.) and running it directly, also in windows 7 compatibility mode.

After the system is restarted, as a sanity check, run the BIOS updater again to check and make sure the latest BIOS is indeed installed on your system.

After the BIOS is updated, Easy Display Manager may be uninstalled.

Answer (score 1):

*Samsung System BIOS Update* does not work on a 64 bit Windows 10.

You will need to install a 32 bit windows version.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Win7 x64 and same message (driver fail, need restart). Went through a lot of tweeks, tried compatibility option for Vista SP1 because my laptop came with that OS but no luck. Tried fresh install of Win 7 X86 but no luck either. 
Solved by running compatibility mode for Win XP SP3, no messages, BIOS updated yay.
Hope it can help others too. It seems that Samsung BIOS application is written for WIN XP and not updated regularly.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the program with compatibility for win 7 and works fine on Win10 (64 bits)

Answer (score 0):

*On a Samsung NP-RV520-S02FR*

I was trying to update from "01PQ" to "07PQ" Bios version because the labtop refused to boot on any kind of SSD Disk (never happened to me before), it was seeing it as a outside peripheral devices like a camera. I tried everything (really !) to fix it and my last hope was the BIOS upgrade.

But it wasn't so easy. I upgraded Winodws 7 Family x64 to Windows 10 x64 on the original hard drive disk. I used the BIOS Update tool from Samsung but it gave me a beautiful BSoD everytime ! Like it's said in the first post of this discussion. So i tried every solution on this post and even more, until only remain one last solution : to launch it from a 32bit Windows version. I got my good old Windows 7 SP1 x86 cd and here we go ! Windows 7 installation worked perfectly and here I am finally on Windows7's desktop. I launch the BIOS Update file "ITEM_20130311_879_WIN_07PQ.exe". And no BSoD !!! Installation had completed ! After a reboot I check the BIOS Version... "07PQ", it really worked !

So now with little hope, I replace my HDD with my SSD (Windows 10 already on it), the one that have never booted 100 times before... And it DID BOOT on the SSD !!!

Conclusion :
Never give up, search again and again on Internet for the right old forgotten forum's post that will solve your problem or at least give you a clue.
For all the time I upgraded BIOS on my friend/client's computers just for the fun of it, without any issue, this one was worth the fight and the patience.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much! The Easy Display Manager allowed it to run on Win 10 64bit system (you have to install it, then run it, even though it won't run since it's a 32bit program, but it provides the drivers to load the BIOS updater. I was given an old Samsung R580 that wouldn't let you into the CMOS with the F2 key.  Rather than take it apart to pull the battery, I decided to update the BIOS (v07) to v.11B.  Now I can edit the CMOS and gave new life to the machine.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1143818)